# Stopping times for a random walk

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

> Let $X=(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be a symmetric random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$
> with $X_0=0$. I have to prove/disprove that $\tau_1=\inf \{n \in
>  \mathbb{N}_0 : n\geq 11, \, X_n\cdot X_{n-10}\leq 5\}$ and
> $\tau_2=\sup \{n \in \mathbb{N}_0 : X_n>42\}$ are stopping times with
> respect to the canonical filtration.

I think that $\tau_1$ is indeed a stopping time whil $\tau_2$ is obviously not a stopping time since we don't know what $n$ is. For $\tau_1$, I have to show that $\{\tau_1\leq n\}\in \mathcal{F}_n$ for all $n$. I believe I have to write this set in terms of unions/intersections/complements of sets I know are in $\mathcal{F}_n$. But I fail to do so. For $\tau_2$ I suppose I have to construct a counter example? But how do I do that in this case?

Comment: To be clear, when you say "canonical filtration," do you mean just the filtration generated by $X$, or the augmented filtration (where we also include all the null-sets of $\mathcal F_{\infty}$)?

Comment: The problem is probably badly posed. Note that $X_{10}X_{10-10}=X_{10}X_0=0<5$ so $\tau_1=10$ surely and I doubt this was intentional.

Comment: @user6247850 The filtration generated by $X$.

Comment: @Snoop You're right. It's $n\geq 11$. I edited it.

Comment: It is clear that $\{\tau_1\leq 10\}=\emptyset$ and for $n\geq 11$ we have $\{\tau_1=n\} = \{X_n\cdot X_{n-10}\leq 5\}\in \mathcal{F}_n$. This shows that $\tau_1$ is a stopping time. The case for $\tau_2$ is a little more interesting. Can you at least see that $\tau_2\equiv \infty$? If your filtration are complete, it would become a stopping time. However, if you just work with the canonical filtration then it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you an idea for $\tau_1$ : by definition, $\tau_1<T$ if and only if for all $10\le n\le T-1$, we have $X_n X_{n-10}> 5$.

Now for each $n$, you can "condition" on the value of $X_n$, since you know it is $\mathbb Z$-valued. In other words, if $X_n =j\in \mathbb N^+$, $X_n X_{n-10}> 5$ holds if and only if $X_{n-10}> 5/j $ (note that $j$ can not be $0$ on that event, do you see why ?). Similarly, if $X_n=-j$, then the condition holds if and only $X_{n-10}< -5/j $.
Formalizing these observations, we can thus write
$$\{\tau_1 < T\} = \bigcap_{10\le n\le T-1}\bigcup_{j\in\mathbb N^+\\
j\ne 0}\left\{X_n=j,X_{n-10}>5/j\right\} \cup \left\{X_n=-j,X_{n-10}<-5/j\right\} $$
Since $\{\tau_1 < T\}$ is made of countable unions and intersections of elements of $\mathcal F_T$ it follows that it is an element of $\mathcal F_T$ itself.
If you understood this, you should be able to make similar construction and prove that $\{\tau_1 \le T\}\in\mathcal F_T$.

For $\tau_2$, you(ve got the correct intuition : "we don't know what $n$ is". To make it formal, just write down the event
$$ \{\tau_2 = T\}=\{X_T > 42\}\cap\bigcap_{n>T} \{X_n\le 42\}$$
Since $\{X_n\le 42\}\not\in \mathcal F_T$ for any $n>T$, it follows that $\tau_2$ is not a stopping time.